# Send email using VBScript on Windows 7

Tags: windows, email, vbscript

I'm trying to understand the ways a Classic ASP or commandline VBScript application can fail to send email.  The script below is based on various sources. When I try to run it from the command/line on a Windows 7 VM, I get the error

> CDO.Message.1: The "SendUsing" configuration value is invalid.

Thing is, I wrote the script working from examples that purported to solve that error! Any advice?

```
Dim fso, stderr, inX, mail, buf, schemaNode

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set StdErr = fso.GetStandardStream(2)

Set mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

schemaNode = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
With  mail.Configuration.Fields 
    .Item(schemaNode & "sendusing") = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP)
    .Item(schemaNode & "smtpserver") = "my/mail/server"
    .Item(schemaNode & "smtpserverport") = 25 
    .Item(schemaNode & "smtpserverpickupdirectory") = "C:\TEMP"
End With

buf = ""
mail.From = "noreply@my/domain"
mail.To = "some/user@my/domain"
mail.Subject = "Test - via VBScript - " & fso.getTempName()

Set inX = fso.OpenTextFile("template.txt", 1)
Do While inX.AtEndOfStream = False
    buf = buf & inX.ReadLine
Loop

mail.TextBody = buf
mail.Send()

StdErr.WriteLine("OK.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never apply the changes to the mail configuration. Also, using a pickup directory is only relevant for submitting mail to a local mail server via pickup (i.e. by placing the mail (file) in a directory from where the mail server picks it up), not when submitting mail via SMTP.

Change this:

```
With mail.Configuration.Fields
    .Item(schemaNode & "sendusing") = 2
    .Item(schemaNode & "smtpserver") = "my/mail/server"
    .Item(schemaNode & "smtpserverport") = 25
    .Item(schemaNode & "smtpserverpickupdirectory") = "C:\TEMP"
End With
```

into this:

```
With mail.Configuration.Fields
    .Item(schemaNode & "sendusing") = 2
    .Item(schemaNode & "smtpserver") = "my/mail/server"
    .Item(schemaNode & "smtpserverport") = 25
    .Update
End With
```

and the problem will disappear.